# what should be equivalent vb.net code for below c# code

Tags: generics

what should be equivalent **vb.net** code for below **c#** code:

```
  public List<T> ExecuteList<T>(string procedureName, List<DbParameter> parameters) where T : new()
  {
        List<T> objects = new List<T>();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Telerik's code converter.

```
Public Function ExecuteList(Of T As New)(procedureName As String, 
                                         parameters As List(Of DbParameter)) As List(Of T)

    Dim objects As New List(Of T)()

End Function
```

[MSDN: Generic types in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try converting using [Telerik Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/)

Comment: Very useful link, but I think you should also directly answer the question (even if it comes from Telerik).

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to explain the answer but I only studied the basics of Visual Basic language quite a long time ago and never actually got a chance to work with it so I just pointed out directing towards the code converter.